# How can i take this array and make into one array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Category"];
    // Retrieve the object by id
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
        // will get sent to the cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
//        NSLog(@"%@",[objects objectAtIndex:1]);
//        NSLog(@"%@",[objects valueForKey:@"mensClothingType"]);
        NSArray * result = [[objects valueForKey:@"mensClothingType"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
   }];
}
```

how can i get all of the 'mensClothingType' from objects and put that into one array? currently if i read out the array 'objects'

i get this:

```
 (
        (
        Shirts
    ),
        (
        Jeans
    )
)
```

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code and show what you have tried. Explain what issue you are having in your attempt.

Comment: Take a look at the `NSArray` method `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray`. If you post your code and what you've tried we can show you how to make it work.

Comment: i updated it @rmaddy

Comment: can you help? @rmaddy

Comment: Why do you find the existing answer unsuitable? Or @DuncanC's comment above? Both provide a solution.

Comment: @CRD the reason why DuncanC's wont work is because what im trying to do is read out all the value of keys within objects into one array.

Comment: @CRD im not trying to add two existing arrays. i guess i had the wrong initial question.

Comment: im going to try Michaels answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSArray* innerArray in outerArray)
{
    for(id object in innerArray)
    {
        [resultArray addObject:object];
    }
}
```